# bash-completion: Adding a quoted suggestion with a space

Tags: bash

I'm adding bash-completion to an existing tool.

After someone passes the `-s` flag, I'd like to offer several options on bash-completion:

- `Closed`
- `Feedback`
- `"In Progress"`
- `New`
- `Rejected`
- `Resolved`

The space in `"In Progress"` is causing a problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
_remote-redmine()
{
    local cur

    COMPREPLY=()
    cur=${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}

    case "${COMP_WORDS[($COMP_CWORD-1)]}" in
        -s)
            s_opts=( "New" "In Progress" "Resolved" "Feedback" "Closed" "Rejected" )
            COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "${s_opts[*]}" -- "$cur") )
            ;;
    esac
    return 0
}
complete -F _remote-redmine remote-redmine
```

When I run the tool, I get:

```
$ remote-redmine -s <tab><tab>
Closed    Feedback  In        New       Progress  Rejected  Resolved
```

But I'd like to get:

```
$ remote-redmine -s <tab><tab>
Closed    Feedback  "In Progress"       New       Rejected  Resolved
```

or

```
$ remote-redmine -s <tab><tab>
Closed    Feedback  In\ Progress        New       Rejected  Resolved
```

---

Things I've tried:

- `s_opts=( ... "In\ Progress" ... )`: No difference
- `s_opts( ... "In\\ Progress" ...)`: No difference
- `s_opts( ... "In\\\ Progress" ...)`: Two options are `In\` and `Progress`
- `s_opts( ... "\"In Progress\"" ...)`: No difference
- `compgen -o nospace ...`: No difference
- `compgen -o noquote ...`: No difference
- At least `compgen` can put `In Progress` on one line, but that doesn't translate into `complete`

  ```
  $ compgen -W 'New "In Progress"'
  New
  In Progress
  ```
- Escaping extra quotes helps with `compgen`, but that doesn't translate into `complete`:

  ```
  $ compgen -W 'New "\"In Progress\""'
  New
  "In Progress"
  ```
- Escaping the space three times does help, but it still doesn;'t translate into `complete`:

  ```
  $ compgen -W 'New In\\\ Progress'
  New
  In\ Progress
  ```
- I thought escaping the space seven times would be promising because then `complete` would resolve a few of those, but that didn't help either:

  ```
  $ compgen -W 'New In\\\\\\\ Progress'
  New
  In\\\ Progress
  ...
  $ remote-redmine -s <tab><tab>
  ...   In\\\  New  Progress ...
  ```
- Bypassing `compgen` will work, but then I lose the auto-fill on single-tabs and filtering on double-tabls

  ```
  COMPREPLY=( ... 'In\ Progress' ... )
  COMPREPLY=( ,,, '"In Progress"' ... )
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with word splitting and the default value of IFS, no surprise.

In

```
compgen -W "${s_opts[*]}"
```

The array expansion with `[*]` joins the array elements to a single string, using the first character of `IFS` as the separator. It's space by default, so the distinction between a space in a value and a space as a separator is lost. Luckily, `compgen -W` interprets the argument as a string of values separated by `IFS` characters, so it works correctly with `[*]` if you just change `IFS` to something like `:` or anything else that doesn't appear in the values.

Then, in

```
COMPREPLY=( $( compgen ...) )
```

you're implicitly splitting the string printed by `compgen` using `IFS` (and passing them through globbing), but `compgen` appears to print the values separated by newlines specifically. Doing that with splitting would then require setting `IFS` to the newline, but really would be more suited for reading with `readarray`, since it uses  newlines anyway and doesn't glob.

So, you could do

```
_remote-redmine() {
    local cur
    local IFS=:

    COMPREPLY=()
    cur=${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}

    case "${COMP_WORDS[($COMP_CWORD-1)]}" in
        -s)
            s_opts=( "New" "In Progress" "Resolves" "Feedback" "Closed" "Rejected" )
            readarray -t COMPREPLY < <( printf "%q\n" $(compgen -W "${s_opts[*]}" -- "$cur"))
            ;;
    esac
    return 0
}
```

Or, since a newline works in both places, you could just set `IFS=$'\n'` and go with splitting the output as before, but you should still disable globbing for the duration of the function, and that's one more piece of global state to save and restore.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Thanks!  I made one small edit to add a `printf "%q"` to preserve `In\ Progress` as one argument.  Without it `In Progress` would auto-complete as a single unit, but `remote-redmine -s In Progress` would see two seperate arguments.

Comment: @Stewart, oh, hmm, right, it just plops whatever it gets directly to the command line, without quoting it itself. I suppose that makes sense if you wanted to autocomplete multiple args, but here, it seems like a bit of a nuisance. Note that if you do `printf "%q\n" $(compgen ...)`, you're again relying on word splitting to split the output of `compgen` to multiple args for `printf`. That won't work here, when we've just set `IFS` to `:`, and the output is newline-separated. It produces the single string `New<NL>In Progress<NL>Resolves<NL>Feedback<NL>Closed<NL>Rejected'`

Comment: We'd need to quote the values of `COMPREPLY` separately, and luckily it seems `COMPREPLY=( "${COMPREPLY[@]@Q}" )` just might work. (Though at the cost of also completing e.g. `New` as `'New'`.) Not that I'm still exactly sure it works correctly with that. And my experience of completion scripts in general isn't too good either, as I recall, most of the ones I've seen manage to fail with whitespace or mess things up otherwise.

Comment: If we set `IFS=$'\n'` then this works well.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Rather than using `compgen`, we just loop over our array and add the items whose prefix is `$cur`:

```
_remote-redmine()
{
    local cur
    local item

    COMPREPLY=()
    cur=${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}

    case "${COMP_WORDS[($COMP_CWORD-1)]}" in
        -s)
            local s_opts=( "New" "In\ Progress" "Resolved" "Feedback" "Closed" "Rejected" )
            for item in "${s_opts[@]}"; do
                case "$item" in
                    ( "$cur"* )
                        COMPREPLY+=( "$item" )
                        ;;
                esac
            done
            ;;
    esac
    return 0
}
complete -F _remote-redmine remote-redmine
```

Note the backslash I added: `"In\ Progress"`. That's a literal part of the item. When you type `In` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, you get `In\ Progress` in the command line: the escape is outside of a double quote now and thus active: it prevents the word splitting.

Comment: Wow nice.  I feel like this is just a simple re-implementation of compgen... without the problems caused by `IFS=` or multiple escapes.  Easy to understand.  Very elegant.